# why foreach in laravel 8 not work, its not looping

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

foreach not working, only displays the first data and does not display the next data, what is the solution? is there something wrong with the code?

this my database
[image]

and this my view
[image]

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
  if ($request->ajax()) {
    $data = Rek_medik::latest()->get();
    return Datatables::of($data)
      ->addIndexColumn()
      ->addColumn('action', function($row){
          $button = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info btn-xs edit_rekmed"></i> Edit</a>';
          $button .= '&nbsp;';
          $button .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="'.$row->id.'" class="detail btn btn-secondary btn-xs detailrekmed"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i> Detail</a>';
            $button .= '&nbsp;';
          $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>';
    return $button;

    })
    ->addColumn('resep', function($row) {
      $resep2 = json_decode($row->resep , true);
      foreach ($resep2 as $data) {
        return '<span class="badge badge-success">'.$data.'</span>';
      }
      })
    ->rawColumns(['action','resep'])
    ->make(true);
  }
  $register = Register::all();
  $pasien = Pasien::all();
  $pegawai = Pegawai::all();
  $obat = Obat::all();
  $koderekmed = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'rek_mediks','field'=>'kode_rekmed', 'length' => 9, 'prefix' =>'RKMD-']);

  return view('admin/rek_medik/index', compact('koderekmed','register','pasien','pegawai','obat'));
}
```

Comment: please add view code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `return`,  then it will die after the first loop. You need to change :

```
$resep2 = json_decode($row->resep , true);
$query = [];
foreach ($resep2 as $data) {
     $query[] =  '<span class="badge badge-success">'.$data.'</span>';
 }
 $query = implode(', ', $query);
 return $query;
})
```